# ubuntu 9.10 Rc scripts no honored

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have created following rc.{#}d structure; however my ssh server is not starting. I see

- Kill -
- /etc/rc0.d/K84ssh
- /etc/rc1.d/K84ssh
- /etc/rc2.d/K84ssh
- /etc/rc4.d/K84ssh
- /etc/rc6.d/K84ssh
- Start -

  - /etc/rc3.d/S16ssh
  - /etc/rc5.d/S16ssh

Answer (score 1):

How did you create them? Manually? You can just use the following:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

For more details, you can see: `man update-rc.d`.
Of course, you need to have the startup script `/etc/init.d/ssh`. As these are just symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

The files in `/etc/rc?.d` are just symbolic links, pointing to files in `/etc/init.d/`. If you do not know what to do for restoring the startup scripts, just reinstall OpenSSH server:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server
```

Your settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will be preserved.